# creating file with dynamic names in for loop

Tags: sh

I'm trying to loop over few linux command and redirect them to a file, I'm having difficulties assigning the file names according to the command names. I'm sure there is a better way to do it but for now this is how I have my script

```
#!/bin/sh
j=0
fileName=ls
fileName1=date
echo $fileName$j
for item in "ls -l >> /home/Desktop/$fileName$j" "date >>/home/Desktop/$fileName$j";do
        eval $item
        j=$((j+1))
done
```

The commands works but it does not create the file names as I am expecting to have ls file and date file. considering I have over 20 commands, what is the best way to get the output of those commands in files with name that correlate to their contents.

I have tried to use eval to have dynamic variable names but with no luck.

Comment: Hi and welcome to Stack Overflow. Since this is a site of learning, I like to point you to the following sites: [BashFAQ: never parse ls](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and [BashFAQ#048:  eval is evil](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048) and [BashFAQ#050: how to build commands](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Comment: thanks @kvantour, I was able to do this in bash, but specifically need it in sh, wasn't able to find good resource there. also the commands here are just examples, not the exact commands I'm looking at. my problem is having dynamic naming for the filename variable so in the loop I can work with it.

Comment: ***Never*** use `for i in $(ls anything)`, see [Bash Pitfalls **#1**](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_i_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29) -- there is a reason that's `#1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never forget `eval` is only one-character away from `evil`... (avoid it). POSIX shell, and all typical shells for that matter, allow you to use the `set` command to set positional parameters as if they had been given on the command line. You can then loop over the positional parameters using a `while` loop.. You use the `shift` command to shift the current positional parameter out moving the next parameter down to `$1` for execution.

Using your provided `ls` and `date` commands, you could do the following in POSIX shell:

```bash
#!/bin/sh

set "ls" "date"   ## set the positional parameters to desired commands

while [ -n "$1" ]; do   ## while positional parameters remain
  $1                    ## execute the current command (parameter)
  shift                 ## shift next parameter to current position
done
```

**Example Use/Output**

In a directory with this example file, you wold get:

```
$  sh loopcmds.sh
README                function-multi-array.sh  permute.sh            readver.sh
arr-fill.sh           hosts                    pinghosts.sh          replace-e-incremental.sh
createnumbereddir.sh  list-removable.sh        posix-arighmetic.sh   write-heredoc.sh
createseqdir.sh       loopcmds.sh              postix-arighmetic.sh  zenity-file-select.sh
dat                   nameref.sh               process-opts.sh
file.txt              ns_record.sh             readroster.sh
Sun 11 Dec 2022 11:57:50 PM CST
```

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have a list of commands which require a specific set of arguments that can be complex (spaces, newlines, ...) :

```
cmd1 arg11 arg12 arg13
cmd2 arg21
cmd3 arg31 arg32
...
cmdn argn1 argn2 ... argnm
```

the output of each of these commands needs to be stored in `cmd1.txt`, `cmd2.txt` ... `cmdn.txt`.

One way to achieve this is in bash using arrays and indirection:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash
# Define commands
cmd_1=( "cmd1" "arg11" "arg12" "arg13" )
cmd_2=( "cmd2" "arg21" )
cmd_3=( "cmd3" "arg31" "arg32" )
..
cmd_n=( "cmdn" "argn1" ... "argnm" )
# Define command list to use indirection
cmd_list=( cmd_1[@] cmd_2[@] ... cmd_n[@] )

# loop over commands
for _ref in "${cmd_list[@]}"; do
   # use indirection to get the full command
   _cmd=( "${!_ref}" )
   # execute the command and write to file 
   "${_cmd[@]}" > "${_cmd[0]}.txt"
done
```

If you require POSIX sh, then it becomes a bit more tricky

Comment: Hmm, final comment *"I was able to do this in bash, but specifically need it in sh..."* would seem to eliminate the use of arrays?